# java testng retry logic

Tags: java, testng

I have written a code for retrying a failed test case in selenium web driver and java.
How should we enhance the script to hold only one record in the test case output even the same test case as been executed multiple times.
I don't want the test output report to contain any redundant result entries.

Code:
Retry Logic :

```
package tests;

import org.testng.IRetryAnalyzer;
import org.testng.ITestResult;

public class Retry implements IRetryAnalyzer {
    private int retryCount         = 0;
    private int maxRetryCount     = 2;   // retry a failed test 2 additional times

    @Override
    public boolean retry(ITestResult result) {
        if (retryCount <maxRetryCount) {
            retryCount++;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Implementation in the class

```
@Test(retryAnalyzer=Retry.class)
    public void example() throws CustomException
    {
        throw new CustomException("Example");
    }
```

Please let me know what changes are needed.

Thanks and Regards
Sushanth.G

Comment: Here it runs three times and in the test output the result is displayed thrice. I want the result to show up only once along with the error message.

Comment: You said: "I don't want the test output report to contain any redundant result entries.", however you failed to mention or show what you are using to generate this report!

Comment: Testng is used to generate the report. It automatically generates it.

Comment: So I guess you have two options. 1) You already modified the behaviour of TestNG, by rerunning failed tests, might as well modify the behaviour of the logging: trap the logger and turn it off when you don't want things logged. 2) Post-process the log: write a utility to parse it and remove duplicates.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem before.
We used jenkins to run CI, and need to make sure all test case results were SUCCESS (even after some times of retry) then we can deploy build.

The solution is adding TestListenerAdapter to re-write test result status to SKIP if this test will be run again.

```
public class MyTestListenerAdapter extends TestListenerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void onTestFailure(ITestResult result) {
        if (result.getMethod().getRetryAnalyzer() != null) {
            MyRetryAnalyzer retryAnalyzer = (MyRetryAnalyzer)result.getMethod().getRetryAnalyzer();

            if(retryAnalyzer.isRetryAvailable()) {
                result.setStatus(ITestResult.SKIP);
            } else {
                result.setStatus(ITestResult.FAILURE);
            }
            Reporter.setCurrentTestResult(result);
        }
    }
}
```

RetryAnalyzer needs to provide another method (isRetryAvailable() in this example) for TestListenerAdapter.

```
public class MyRetryAnalyzer implements IRetryAnalyzer {
    private static int MAX_RETRY_COUNT = 3;

    AtomicInteger count = new AtomicInteger(MAX_RETRY_COUNT);

    public boolean isRetryAvailable() {
        return (count.intValue() > 0);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean retry(ITestResult result) {
        boolean retry = false;
        if (isRetryAvailable()) {
            System.out.println("Going to retry test case: " + result.getMethod() + ", " + (MAX_RETRY_COUNT - count.intValue() + 1) + " out of " + MAX_RETRY_COUNT);
            retry = true;
            count.decrementAndGet();
        }
        return retry;
    }
}
```

Now we can add this TestListenerAdapter to test class.

```
@Listeners({MyTestListenerAdapter.class})
public class AppTest {
    @Test(retryAnalyzer=MyRetryAnalyzer.class)
    public void testSum(){
        MyClass c = new MyClass();
        Assert.assertEquals(c.sum(2, 3), 5);
    }
}
```

Please see full example here: https://github.com/haojiwu/testng-retry-example

Comment: Tried and report is ok but maven build still fails. Any other idea?. Thanks!